# Using JPA to specify that to get the value for a field a join is required

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I may very well be barking up the wrong tree or indeed just barking mad but I have an issue.

I have a class which as looks like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class MyClass {

    @Column(name="FIELD_1")
    private String fieldOne;

}
```

Please assume all getters and setters that are required are present.

So now let us suppose I need to add an additional field called `myRequiredField` added into this class however the problem being is this field is gathered from the database by performing a join onto a table called `table2` using `FIELD_1`.

In sql I would likely do something like this:

```
select t1.FIELD_1, 
       t2.myRequiredValue
 from table1 t1 
 join table2 t2 on t1.FIELD_1 = t2.FIELD_1
```

Is there a way to do this using annotations and if so can someone give me an example as to how to do this.

Thank you very much in advance for any assistance rendered.

Edit

ok so let us say i have this class as well:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
public class MyClass2 {


    @Column(name="FIELD_1")
    private String FIELD_1;

    @Column(name="MY_REQUIRED_FIELD")
    private String myRequiredField;

}
```

so I now have these 2 classes whereby MyClass2's FIELD_1 can be used to joing from MyClass2's FIElD_1 in order to get myRequiredField.

I am struggling to figure out exactly how to do this.

Essentially what I want to be able to do is when I get an instantiation of MyClass1 I want to be able to get a corresponding MyClass2 as if i had performed the above sql query.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Why not search for "secondary table", or just read the docs for any reputable JPA provider

Comment: Please create a concrete example. If the column is in another table, the corresponding field should also be in another entity, mapped to this other table.

Comment: Please see the above edit, I also should add that while I am using the javax.persistance.* package for annotations, hibernate is also in the mix.

Comment: That's far from concrete. Replace MyClass1 and MyClass2 by your concrete entities. The real ones. And tell us which kind of association exists between them. For example: entity Car which has a OneToMany association with entity Wheel, using a foreign key in Wheel pointing to the Car ID.

Comment: and while doing that, mention how that fits in with your earlier statement about adding a field to that same first class. If you're not doing that now, then rephrase the whole question so people know what to answer